# Morton curve for non cubic areas that are a power of two

Tags: c++, math, raytracing, z-order-curve

While optimizing a ray tracer I was trying to improve data locality for the intersection datastructure using a Morton space filling curve, except that my 3D space is not cubic (eg. 512x512x256). All sides are a power of two, but not all sides are the same length.

I have been unable to find any examples for non square Morton curves where the sides are a power of two. If it matters I can guarantee that the x/y axis are the same size with only the z axis being a different length.

[image]
Note how the width is 2x height, but it could also be 3x or 4x or any other. I have been unable to find a way how to do this.

Ideally the solution would be fast as the Morton code has to be calculated a lot. So my question is: How do I generate a space filling morton curve for non-cubic spaces? This is specifically for the GPU (Cuda).

The conditions on the dimensions are:
x, y, z are a power of two
x == y
x, y >= z
Or if easier
x, y > z

Comment: Do you know if the width will _always_ be 2x height?

Comment: Also, is this computation done by a GPU? (It can have a huge impact on performance)

Comment: @Jean-BenoitHarvey y The sizes of x, y, z are known at compile time. The relation between x/y and z is variable. Sometimes x is z * 2, sometimes z * 4 or higher. This is on the GPU yes. I have also edited the main post to highlight this.

Comment: Relating to your last comment, does this mean that `x` is _always_ the smallest variable (you mention in the edit "or any other"... can the width be 0.5x height)? (Or is there a way to know which variable is the smallest)?

Comment: x, y >= z. If it is easier I can alternatively guarantee x,y > z. It's also the case that x == y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would probably break for, say, nz=11, but for half of the size of the XY square it seems to work for me

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

static inline uint32_t spread(uint32_t x)
{
    x = (x | (x << 10)) & 0x000F801F;
    x = (x | (x << 4)) & 0x00E181C3;
    x = (x | (x << 2)) & 0x03248649;
    x = (x | (x << 2)) & 0x09249249;

    return x;
}

static inline uint32_t morton(const uint32_t x, const uint32_t y, const uint32_t z)
{
    return spread(x) << 0 | spread(y) << 1 | spread(z) << 2;
}


auto main() -> int {
    int nx = 32;
    int ny = 32;
    int nz = 16;

    for (int iz = 0; iz != nz; ++iz)
    {
        for (int iy = 0; iy != ny; ++iy)
        {
            for (int ix = 0; ix != nx; ++ix)
            {
                auto m = morton(ix, iy, iz);

                std::cout << m << '\n';
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

UPDATE

How to make Morton code work for, say, 256x256x64 (8bit*8bit*6bit): you have to spread X and Y non-equidistantly, taking into account number of bits in Z. Basically, for cube you spread evenly: each bit at position
0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24,
leaving space for other two bits from orthogonal axes.

So there is equidistant spread for a cube. But for the case when you have only 6 bits from Z to insert, you have to have 6 distances of 3, but no Z bits for last gap, thus last gap for X and Y spread should be only 1 bit wide. Thus, non-equidistant spread in X and Y.

Something along the line: if Nx=Ny are number of bits in XY plane, and Nz!=Nx or Ny is number of bits along Z axis,
spread gap should be 2 bits for Nz bits and gap of 1 bit for what is left. So two spread routines - one for X&Y with non-equidistant spread which now depends on Nz, and existing spread function for Z axis.

Ok, here is a working version, seems to be doing right thing

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

#define func auto

func spreadZ(uint32_t v) -> uint32_t { // 2bit gap spread
    v = (v | (v << 10)) & 0x000F801F;
    v = (v | (v << 4)) & 0x00E181C3;
    v = (v | (v << 2)) & 0x03248649;
    v = (v | (v << 2)) & 0x09249249;

    return v;
}

func spreadXY(const uint32_t v, const uint32_t bitsZ) -> uint32_t {
    uint32_t mask_z = (1U << bitsZ) - 1U; // to mask bits which are going to have 2bit gap

    uint32_t lo{ v & mask_z }; // lower part of the value where there are Z bits
    lo = spreadZ(lo);          // 2bit gap spread

    uint32_t hi = v >> bitsZ; // high part of the value, 1bit gap

    // 1bit gap spread
    hi = (hi ^ (hi << 8)) & 0x00ff00ffU;
    hi = (hi ^ (hi << 4)) & 0x0f0f0f0fU;
    hi = (hi ^ (hi << 2)) & 0x33333333U;
    hi = (hi ^ (hi << 1)) & 0x55555555U;

    return lo + (hi << 3*bitsZ); // combine them all together
}

func morton(const uint32_t x, const uint32_t y, const uint32_t z, const uint32_t bitsZ) -> uint32_t {
    return spreadXY(x, bitsZ) << 0 | spreadXY(y, bitsZ) << 1 | spreadZ(z) << 2;
}

func ispowerof2(const uint32_t n) -> bool {
    return n && (!(n & (n - 1u)));
}

func bit_pos(const uint32_t n) -> uint32_t {
    if (!ispowerof2(n))
        throw -1;

    uint32_t i{ 1u }, pos{ 1u };

    while (!(i & n)) { // Iterate through bits of n till we find a set bit, i&n will be non-zero only when 'i' and 'n' have a same bit         
        i = i << 1; // unset current bit and set the next bit in 'i' 

        ++pos; // increment position 
    }

    return pos;
}

func main() -> int {
    int nx = 256;
    int ny = 256;

    int nz = 256; //256...128...64...32...16...8...4...2...1 all works
    int bitsZ = bit_pos(nz) - 1; // should be doing try/catch

    for (int iz = 0; iz != nz; ++iz)
    {
        for (int iy = 0; iy != ny; ++iy)
        {
            for (int ix = 0; ix != nx; ++ix)
            {
                auto m = morton(ix, iy, iz, bitsZ);

                std::cout << m << '\n';
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for attempting a solution except that this is a regular morton curve. The standard morton algorithm works fine if the last component dimension is half of the other ones since it just drops the most significant bit. I'm specifically looking for a morton curve algorithm where the last component can be any power of two number.

Comment: @Eejin I agree, but you started with 512x512x256 and I looked into my code and found it is working. I agree that for other Z dimensions there shall be changes. I'll look into it

Comment: @Eejin I think I figured it out, please check update. No code for a time being